# How to show the version of a single Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, bash, kernel-module

How is it possible to see the version of a single kernel module in Linux?
With the command `lsmod`, I can see something like this:

```
ata_piix               18561  2 
libata                154449  2 pata_acpi,ata_piix
ehci_hcd               34935  0 
scsi_mod              111801  4 sg,sr_mod,sd_mod,libata
usbcore               119612  6 gspca_m5602,gspca_main,usbhid,uhci_hcd,ehci_hcd
```

But is not possible show the info about a single kernel module.
Anybody know how is possible do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `modinfo` command to list information about modules:

```
$ /sbin/modinfo your_module_name
```

I'm not sure a version string is required though, so some modules might not have it.

Comment: Yes there is a field named "srcversion".
Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Use modinfo, check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/10439/how-do-you-check-the-version-of-a-ko-kernel-module-in-linux) page, and use this syntax:

`modinfo your_module`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839024/how-to-find-the-version-of-a-compiled-kernel-module) question of SO.

Or use [pmvers](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmvers).